# VirtualEnv for software dependencies

Tags: linux, virtualenv

I am trying to install some software dependencies without root permission and have been using virtualenv. The following are my commands:

```
module load python
virtualenv directoryName
pip install numpy
```

But, when I do this I get the following error:

> error: could not create '/N/soft/python/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy': Permission denied

Does anyone know how I can resolve this?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you first need to activate the virtualenv.

```
virtualenv test
source test/bin/activate
pip install numpy
```

You will see that your terminal line will change. More info on the subject is here: http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/virtualenv.html#usage